# Получить информацию о пользователе facebook при авторизации

Tags: meteor

Делаю на сайте авторизацию через соц.линки (facebook), хочу получать о пользователе дополнительную информацию (например, список друзей). Запрос на разрешение сделал, но вот как получать эти данные, разобраться вообще не могу. Знаю, что нужно смотреть Graph API, так же, установить несколько пакетов в метеоре, для обработки этих данных. Но вот какие пакеты, как их настроить, даже малейшего понятия не имею. Буду благодарен, кто сможет описать (хотя бы вкратце) шаги, которые нужно проделать для получения этой информации.

Comment: Смотрите сюда: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

Answer (score 1):

Это делается с помощью запроса к API. Вот небольшой пример. На сервере:
Не забудьте установить пакет http (meteor add http).

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user){ 
  if (user.profile.services.facebook.friends === undefined) { //если списка друзей нет, сделать вызов к API facebook, facebookIdHere называется у вас по другому.
    Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/" + user.profile.facobook.facebookIdHere + "/friendlists", 
      {params: {"apikey": "Ваш ключ API"}, headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}},function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
        var friends = result.data.blablabla //тут уже сами посмотрите как придет ответ
        Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId}, {$set: {user.profile.facebook.friendList: friends}}); //обновить пользователя 
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Не забудьте поменять названия объектов и ключ API на свои.
Наверняка есть ошибки, но примерная схема понятна, буду надеяться.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ulogin и callback функцию, ну или подобный сервис, намного упростите себе жизнь. https://ulogin.ru/faq.php
Тут в принципе описано всё что можно получить от соц сетей.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.